# SignalR list of object undefined

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am trying to display on the console a list of object But it doesn't show the objects...

[image]

Here is the javascript I use to display the object received from the server :

```
connection.on("ReceiveLog", function (chatMessages) {

console.log(chatMessages);

for (var item in chatMessages) {

    // work with key and value
    var encodedMsg = item.User + " says " + item.Message;
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent = encodedMsg;
        document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
} });
```

The server is sending a list of ChatMessage. Here is the ChatMessage class :

```
public class ChatMessage
{
    string User { get; set; }
    string Message { get; set; }

    public ChatMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        this.User = user;
        this.Message = message;
    }
}
```

Why are my objects completely broken ? When I break the code on the server side, it really sends the list correctly. The problem seems to be from the javascript or maybe I need to serialize from the server side ?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set all the property of the object Public like so :

```
public class ChatMessage
{
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public ChatMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        this.User = user;
        this.Message = message;
    }
}
```

It works now.